# difference between 'new AnyClass;' and 'new AnyClass();'

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Hi!

What is the difference between the follow statements?

```
AnyClass *i1 = new AnyClass();
AnyClass *i2 = new AnyClass;
```

Both statements compile and run equally.

Is there no difference?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new).